# Remote Desktop Connection licensing error

Tags: rdp, licensing

I am using OpenVPN to connect my server, and after I start openvpn, service works, i can ping my servers, I even can connect to other servers, but on this one specific i get error after long time waiting:

[image]

Any sugestions what to do.

From other computers same connection works, and also I have this problem with some computers, that have diffrent versions of Windows.

Also on logs from AD and TS, I can not find anything, I have also restart all servers (AD, TS, VPN)

Comment: Do you use a admin account to connect ?

Comment: no, I use other account to connect

Comment: ... and also as admin I get same error